# É verdade que o Codeigniter vai acabar?

Tags: codeigniter

Vi por alto uma informação falando que o **Codeigniter** vai acabar. Então vim até aqui para ter uma informação mais precisa. Isso é verdade?

Answer (score 3):

> Ao contrário do que muitos, inadvertida e irrefletidamente, estão pensando e divulgando pela web à fora, o CodeIgniter vai continuar, sim, e essa história de, num futuro próximo, ele ser assumido por outra empresa/organização/conjunto/grupamento, deve ser encarado como algo positivo!

Fonte da citação acima e a melhor explicação que já encontrei para o assunto lá do CodeIgniterBrasil: http://codeigniterbrasil.com/noticias/ellislab-procura-um-novo-dono-para-o-codeigniter/

Comment: Então é tranquilo continuar usando?

Comment: Por favor, coloque o que o link diz na resposta, pois caso ele saia do ar, a resposta continuará aqui.

Comment: Eu não posso ainda adicionar uma resposta antes de 8 horas. =[

Comment: Se o `Codeigniter` acabasse, seria um favor a toda humanidade :)